# How to solve $x^2 y''+(2x-1)y' = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation $x^2 y''+(2x-1)y' = 0$ ?

I tried with $y'=v$ but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Using your substitution, we have
$$\frac{v^\prime}{v} = \frac{1-2x}{x^2}.$$
Integrate both sides, and you are done.